# Maximum of $\frac{a-b}{c}+\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a>b>c>0$ such that $7a+8b=15c+24\sqrt[3]{abc}$, find the maximum value of

$$\frac{a-b}{c}+\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b}$$

I tried to use $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \ge 3$ so that

$$\frac{a-b}{c}+\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b}=(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a})-(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b})\le (\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}) -3$$

and here I am stuck.

I don't know how to find the maximum of $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}$.

Comment: A $\le$ doesn't help much with finding a maximum. I'd try adding up the fractions (it looks like much will just go away, and the $abc$ in your restriction hints at something like it).

Comment: Adding up gives $\frac{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a-ab^2-bc^2-ca^2}{abc}$. How to connect it to the restriction?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that:

$$\frac{a-b}{c}+\frac{b-c}{a}+\frac{c-a}{b} = \frac{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)}{abc}$$

Now, let $x=a-b > 0$ and $y=b-c>0$. Then $a-c=x+y$ and from the condition

$$7a+8b=15c+24\sqrt[3]{abc}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt[3]{abc}=\frac{7x+15y}{24}$$

Therefore, using AM-GM:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)}{abc} &= \frac{24^3 xy(x+y)}{(7x+15y)^3}\\
&= \frac{24^3}{144}\cdot \frac{(4x)\cdot (12y)\cdot 3(x+y)}{(7x+15y)^3}\\
&\leq \frac{24^3}{144\cdot 27} \cdot \frac{[4x+12y+3(x+y)]^3}{(7x+15y)^3}\\
&= \frac{32}{9}
\end{aligned}$$

Equality occurs when $a : b : c=9 : 3 : 1$.

Comment: incredible nice solution! +1

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, thanks :)

Comment: Amazing!!! [+1] How did you come up with the solution? What is the idea behind this incredible approach?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva, After noticing that the sum of the fractions equals the negative of their product and after noticing the choice of $7,8,-15$ in the condition so that $7a+8b-15c = 7(a-b)+15(b-c)$, it felt like a natural approach to substitute $x=a-b,\ y=b-c$ (reduce the question from three variables to two). Then it becomes a problem of maximizing a two variable functions and with some calculus I found it maximizes when $x=3y$. Knowing the equality case, it becomes easier to see how to apply AM-GM :)

Comment: Lovely solution +1